# cant get pagination by when i use other method than count_all codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, count, pagination

I have used join query to fetch the data, when some data is deleted from the table which is joined then it creating problem with pagination

controller code

```
function index($msg='',$offset = 0)
{
        $data = array('title'=>'Towns','message'=>'', 'link_add'=>site_url('manage/town/add'), 'edit_link'=>site_url('manage/town/edit'), 'tbl'=>'towns' );
        $uri_segment = 4;
        $offset = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);
        // load data
        $value=('towns.Id,towns.Name as TownName,city.Name as CityName,city.Status,towns.Status,towns.TaxAmount');
        $data['list_records'] = $this->admin_model->get_joinlist($data['tbl'],$value,'city','city.Id = towns.cityId','left outer','towns.Id','asc',array('towns.Status !='=>'Delete','city.Status'=>'Enable'),$this->limit, $offset)->result();
        if($msg=='m')$data['message'] = 'New Town has been added successfully!';
        // generate pagination
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('manage/town/index/');
        $this->total = $this->admin_model->**count_all**($data['tbl'],array('Status !='=>'Delete'));
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->total;
        $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;
        $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['j'] = 0 + $offset;
        $data['total_rows']= $this->total;
        // load view
        $this->load->view('manage/includes/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('manage/town', $data);
        $this->load->view('manage/includes/footer');
}

         <?php
```

class Admin_model extends CI_Model {

```
//listing with join
public function get_joinlist($table,$value,$table2,$condi,$join_type,$order_by,$order,$where,$limit, $offset)
{
    $this->db->select($value);
    $this->db->join($table2,$condi,$join_type);
    $this->db->order_by($order_by,$order);
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $query= $this->db->get($table, $limit, $offset);
}

//For pagination
function count_all($table,$where)
{   
   return $this->db->where($where)
   ->count_all_results($table);
}
function num_rows($table)
{   
   return $this->db->affected_rows($table);
}
```

Comment: Any Help would be appriciated . i want to use num_rows fun in place of count_all

Comment: You can't use num_rows because that will always be 100% of the limit, thus, no pagination

Comment: Thanks for reply,
yeah oh k but thats the exact problem i am facing.

Comment: But when we pass any static integer value in config['total_rows']='2' it is generating pagination,and when i echo the result of affected rows which also returns an int so what the problem in pagination

Comment: Not sure looking into it now

Comment: and yeah num_rows is just a name of method in that i have used affected_rows method as you can see in model code
function num_rows($table)
{   
   return $this->db->affected_rows($table);
}

Comment: Or you can suggest any other way for creating pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
   public function get_joinlist($table,$value,$table2,$condi,$join_type,$order_by,$order,$where,$limit, $offset)
{
    $this->db->start_cache();
    $this->db->select($value);
    $this->db->join($table2,$condi,$join_type);
    $this->db->order_by($order_by,$order);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->stop_cache();

    $query['num_rows']=$this->db->get($table)->num_rows();
    $query['results']=$this->db->get($table, $limit, $offset);
    $this->db->flush_cache();
    return $query;
}
```

This way, your model will return an array with the the total rows of the join and the results limited by offset and limit rows